# Single or Double Pointer for Struct pointers

Tags: c, pointers, struct, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

I was trying to write some code to check the function of pointers for struct pointers when calling a function.

I tried using single pointer for tree or linked list but found that normally if I write a void function and head or root is not global it is giving me segmentation fault.

The only solution that I find is either to return the value of head(or root) or to use double pointer if I don't want to return anything(but need to call with &).

My codes are:

```
//This one gives Segmentation Error always.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>

struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
};

typedef struct node node;

void addnode(node *head, node *tail, int d)
{
    node *newnode = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
    newnode->data = d;
    newnode->next = NULL;
    if(head==NULL)
    {
        head = tail = newnode;
    }
    else
    {
        tail->next = newnode;
        tail = newnode;
    }
}


//This one also works [but sometimes gives Segmentation Error (No Idea why)]. But it has a return
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>

struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
};

typedef struct node node;

void addnode(node *head, node *tail, int d)
{
    node *newnode = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
    newnode->data = d;
    newnode->next = NULL;
    if(head==NULL)
    {
        head = tail = newnode;
    }
    else
    {
        tail->next = newnode;
        tail = newnode;
    }
    return head;
}


//This one also works fine but here I don't need to return anything.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>

struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
};

typedef struct node node;

void addnode(node **head, node **tail, int d)   // Here head and tail is called with & eg: addnode(&head1,&tail1,data);
{
    node *newnode = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
    newnode->data = d;
    newnode->next = NULL;
    if(head==NULL)
    {
        *head = *tail = newnode;
    }
    else
    {
        (*tail)->next = newnode;
        *tail = newnode;
    }  //No return
}
```

My question is why is this error occurring? Don't we use pointers even with variables when we want
to have more than one values from a function which can have only a single return statement?

Besides regarding the single and double pointer don't we do the first case with array pointers as well and besides even in array(or any other pointer type), when we do *arr1 = *arr2;
then doesn't modifying arr1 modifies arr2(since now they point to the same data)?  If that is the case why do I need to use double pointer here to modify and access them?

I am really confused.

Please help.

Comment: Read more on 'call by reference' & 'call by value'. In your case 'call by reference' works; which is a double pointer, since the variable is a pointer already.

Comment: A pointer is a variable containing an address to somewhere in memory. So if you pass the address that pointer contains you can not modify  this value baca use you do not know where the pointer that holds this address is in memory. To be able to modify it, you need to have its address, that is the address of the pointer ( eg : &head) which is a pointer to a pointer = double pointer.

Answer (score 2):

This function

```
void addnode(node *head, node *tail, int d)
```

deals with copies of the values of the original pointers `head` and `tail` used as argument expressions. Changing the copies does not influence on the original pointers.

This function

```
void addnode(node *head, node *tail, int d)
{
    //...
    return head;
}
```

has the return type `void`. So the compiler should issue an error message because a return statement shall not return a value if the return type of a function is `void`.

But if you will declare the function the following way

```
node * addnode(node *head, node *tail, int d)
{
    //...
    return head;
}
```

nevertheless it will have the same problem as the first function relative to the pointer `tail` because again the function will deal with a copy of the original pointer `tail` and the new value of the pointer will not be returned to the caller.

The definition of this function

```
void addnode(node **head, node **tail, int d)   // Here head and tail is called with & eg: addnode(&head1,&tail1,data);
{
    node *newnode = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
    newnode->data = d;
    newnode->next = NULL;
    if(head==NULL)
    {
        *head = *tail = newnode;
    }
    else
    {
        (*tail)->next = newnode;
        *tail = newnode;
    }  //No return
}
```

has a bug. Instead of this if statement

```
    if(head==NULL)
```

you have to write

```
    if ( *head == NULL )
```

The function work because the pointers `head` and `tail` are passed to the function by reference through pointers to them. So dereferencing the pointers like for example in this statement

```
        *head = *tail = newnode;
```

you have a direct access to the original pointers (instead of dealing with copies of the values of the original pointers) and can change them.

But in any case your approach is not good.

You should declare one more structure that will incorporate the pointers `head` and `tail` as for example

```
typedef struct list
{
    node *head;
    node *tail;
} list;
```

then in main you can declare an object of the structure type like

```
list list1 = { .head =  NULL, .tail = NULL };
```

In this case the function `addnode` will look the following way

```
int addnode( list *lst, int data )
{
    node *newnode = malloc( sizeof( node ) );
    int success = newnode != NULL;

    if ( success )
    {
        newnode->data = data;
        newnode->next = NULL;

        if ( lst->head == NULL )
        {
            lst->head = newnode;
        }
        else
        {
            lst->tail->next = newnode;
        }

        lst->tail = newnode;
    }

    return success;
}
```

and the function can be called like for example

```
addnode( &list1, data );
```

or

```
if ( !addnode( &list1, data ) )
{
    puts( "Error. Not enough memory" );
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It really cleared a lot of my doubts. But I have two questions: Firstly in the third case ignoring the tail part, why do I still need a double pointer for head? And if I use a single pointer then, as you said these are copies, so then why does it not happen with array pointers? If you could kindly clear this I will be very grateful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @SuryaMajumder I have not understood your first question. All is explained in my answer. As for the second question then when you pass an array to a function it is implicitly converted to pointer to its first element. So using the pointer and the pointer arithmetic you can change any element of the array . In fact elements of the array are passed by reference through a pointer to them. That is a call like this function( array ); is the same as to write function( &array[0] );

Comment: Thank you a lot @Vlad from Moscow. Thank you very much.